# Understanding proof of uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I know of the standard proof of uncountably of the reals by showing that $[0,1]$ is uncountable. But I'm looking at a proof that claims not to consider $[0,1]$ but establishes uncountability and I'm trying to understand how it works. The argument goes like this.

> There is no map $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ that can be surjective, because writing out the decimal or binary expansions, we get:
> \begin{align*}
> f(0) = a_{00}. a_{01} a_{02} a_{03} \ldots \\
> f(1) = a_{10} . a_{11} a_{12} a_{13} \ldots \\
> f(2) = a_{20} . a_{21} a_{22} a_{23} \ldots \\
> f(3) = a_{30}. a_{31} a_{32} a_{33} \ldots 
> \end{align*}
> Let $y = b_0. b_1 b_2 b_3$ where $b_j \neq a_{jj}$ for each $j$, so $y \neq f(j)$ for all $j$, so $f$ isn't surjective.

My question is, as someone who doesn't understand too much about binary, is: is it possible to enumerate every real number in this way? Is this a binary expansion of each real number that only has one digit before the decimal point? Can $a_{00}$, $a_{10}$, and so forth be a multi-digit number? Or is this proof, in essence, restricted to $[0,1]$?

Comment: In this proof it seems $a_{n0}$ can be arbitrary integer number, even negative. It's cleaner, however, to restrict to $[0,1]$.

Comment: That is not a major problem, as if you need $b_0 \in \{0,1\}$ you can always make it different from $a_{00}$. There is another issue that almost all dyadic rationals have two binary expressions and you run the risk that $b$ may turn out to be one already listed a different way

Comment: It says you can choose between binary and decimal. Maybe it's easier to understand the proof if you think about decimal? (Also note that the binary case has a weakness related to the well-known (decimal) identity $0.999\ldots =1$).

Comment: This *is* the standard diagonalization proof. And there *are* numbers with a non-unique binary or decimal expansion, but those are countable.

Comment: So just to be clear, the standard diagonalization proof is for the first digit to just be some integer, positively negative?